# Sublime Text 2 doesn't generate a github token

Tags: github, sublimetext2

I'm trying to install a [GitHub:Gist plugin for Sublime Text 2](https://github.com/bgreenlee/sublime-github). But I can't menage to generate a GitHub token. The manual way doesn't work with windows because I can't run cURL in cmd. The automated way also doesn't work for some reason. It says that I've to enter my username and my password. After doing that nothing happens and when I try to execute another command it says it again.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the GitHub web interface to create the token.

1. login to GitHub
2. Go to Account settings (top right corner)
3. Select Applications from the left hand navigation bar
4. Click on "Create New Token" next to Personal Access Tokens
5. Follow the instructions and then copy the newly created token
6. In Sublime's Preferences, navigate to "Package Settings" –> "Gist" –> "Settings - User" and paste the token in the quotes next to the "token": key

A good reference for this and other actions related to Gists in Sublime can be found here: https://github.com/condemil/Gist